# Disable option based on method in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, html-select

I'm trying to disable option based on method.

Example I have 4 options:

```
A
B
C
D
```

My method (example) :

```
if(name == A) {
disable select for A.
}
```

My code:

```
this.http.getDataFromServer("api/....).subscribe((resp) => {
  
  this.code = resp.data["route"];
  console.log(this.code);
});
```

In `this.code` I have multiple data. This is the HTML in the component:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="route_code">
                    Route Code
                </label>
                <select type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="route_code" (change)="codeSelected($event.target.value)">

               <option [value]="r.id"  *ngFor="let r of code" [disabled]="disable()">
                        {{r.code}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Here I have my HTML code where `r.code` are the options.

After searching I found `[disable]` and I can assign it to a method `disable()`

Component.ts has this code:

```
disable(){
}
```

What should I add within the disable method? For example I want to disable an option if r.code == "A". Could you help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to pass the value to disable as an argument:

component.html

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="route_code">
        Route Code
    </label>
    <select type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="route_code" (change)="codeSelected($event.target.value)">
        <option [value]="r.id" *ngFor="let r of code" [disabled]="disable(r.code)">
            {{r.code}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

component.ts

```js
disable(code: string): boolean {
  return code === "A";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the current `r` in your method.

```
<option [value]="r.id"  *ngFor="let r of code" [disabled]="disable(r)">
        {{r.code}}
</option>
```

Then in disable method you can receive that value which you passed like this.

```
disable(r){
 return r.code === "A";
}
```

This expression will return `true` or `false`.

This solution should work.